# React & Redux - state getting empty after route changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building a react & redux application and the problem I'm having is that after I do `browserHistory.push('/myroute')` and being successfully routed, I see that my state has been cleared, and while I need some data that's on the state from the previous route.. I still haven't found out if this is natural or not

My case is that I need to transfer data between routes.. I thought that is what state is for

this is my log:

```
 action @ 16:21:35.917 ON_ACTIVATE_FINISHED
counter.js:68 Object {counter: Object, registerReducer: Object, routing: Object}
core.js:97  action @ 16:21:35.928 @@router/LOCATION_CHANGE
register.js:9 Object {}
core.js:97  action @ 16:21:38.840 INPUT_PW_CHANGED
```

`routes.js`:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './containers/App';
import HomePage from './containers/HomePage';
import CounterPage from './containers/CounterPage';
import RegisterPage from './containers/RegisterPage';


export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={CounterPage} />
    <Route path="/counter" component={CounterPage} />
    <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
  </Route>
);
```

`CounterPage.js`:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Counter from '../components/Counter';
import * as CounterActions from '../actions/counter';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    counter: state.counter,
    key: state.key
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(CounterActions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

`RegisterPage.js`:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Register from '../components/Register';
import * as RegisterActions from '../actions/register';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    pw: state.pw
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(RegisterActions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register);
```

`reducers/counter.js`:

```
import { Router, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
export const INPUT_KEY_CHANGED = 'INPUT_KEY_CHANGED';
export const ACTIVATE_KEY = 'ACTIVATE_KEY';
export const ON_ACTIVATE_FINISHED = 'ON_ACTIVATE_FINISHED';

export function onInputChanged(e) {
    return {
        type: INPUT_KEY_CHANGED,
        data: e.target.value
    };
}

export function activate() {
    return {
        type: ACTIVATE_KEY
    };
}

export function onActivateFinished(json) {
    return {
        type: ON_ACTIVATE_FINISHED,
        json
    }
}

const SERVER_ADDRESS = 'http://*******:9001';
export const fetchActivationKey = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    var request = require('request-promise');

    dispatch(activate())
    const key = getState().counter.key;
    return request(`${SERVER_ADDRESS}/invite/${key}`)
        .then((fHost) => {
            return request(`http://${fHost}:9000/api/start/${key}`)
        })
        .then(json => {
            dispatch(onActivateFinished(json))
            let currentState = getState();
            if (currentState.counter.model.status === 0) {
                hashHistory.push('/register');
            }
        });
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you may need to save state before redirecting back to the new route

Comment: Can you share your route configuration and how are you mapping the redux store to component's props in the component before routing and in the second component which is rendered after the routing

Comment: @Swapnil, Added

Comment: @PaulStoner, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: So do you want to access state.counter when you navigate from /counter to /register ?

Comment: @Swapnil, exactly

Comment: Did you try mapping state.counter in mapStateToProps of RegisterPage.js file ?

Comment: like this? function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      counter: state.counter
  };
}, I tried... doesn't work

Comment: for me, there is not enough information. sorry. but what are you doing on the counter page that takes you back to the register page?

Comment: @PaulStoner, hashHistory.push('/register'). Plus, I'd be happy to share everything you need...

Comment: no worries. I wish to assist you. I wasn't clear in my last comment. what exactly is the counter page doing? Would you please post that code

Comment: If the counter is maintained in redux state then you shouldn't loose it over routing using react-router. You sould be able to access state.counter in mapStateToProps. Try consoling it in mapStateToProps. Read [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1094) also

Comment: @PaulStoner, I added the reducer of the counter page. You can see that fetchActivationKey and lastly, a navigation occurs

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store and on my own app, it should look like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="foo" component={Foo}/>
        <Route path="bar" component={Bar}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

But I don't see the `Provider` and the `Router` in your code, the `Provider` is here to pass the main state to all components and without it I'm not sure it would work properly.

> *Normally, you can’t use `connect()` without wrapping the root component in `Provider`.*

Comment: I have these configurations on my project in my `index.js` file, I just stated the routes in an external file.. my root component is wrapped with `Provider`

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a try at this.

Take this code

```
.then(json => {
  dispatch(onActivateFinished(json))
  let currentState = getState();
  if (currentState.counter.model.status === 0) {
    hashHistory.push('/register');
  }
});
```

and change it to this:

```
.then(json => {
  dispatch(onActivateFinished(json))
  let currentState = getState();
  this.setState({counter: currentState.counter});
  if (currentState.counter.model.status === 0) {
    hashHistory.push('/register');
  }
});
```

I'm still learning React and by no means am any kind of expert. So I am not 100% certain this will work. But it is an effort to assist based off of what I currently know.